# Google Charts to Hide a Row and Modify Tooltip

Tags: tooltip, google-visualization

I was able to get the following code by referencing this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921097/hide-a-row-aka-series-in-google-chart) 
to work but am having a hard time changing the tooltip

So I worked with making the tooltip functional and got that to work but am having a very difficult time getting both to work

Thanks!

Code Sample 1: Hide A Row

```
     <html>                                                                                     
    <head>                                                                                     
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>              
      <script type="text/javascript">    
  function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'x');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Attention Phase Harmony');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Clarity of Periphery'); 
      data.addColumn('number', 'Body Temperature');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Clarity of Center of Attention');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Energetic Phenomena');    
      data.addColumn('number', 'Pain-Pleasure');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Mental Illness');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Mind Speed');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Powers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Sleep'); 

      data.addRow([1,    4,      0,      0,      1,       -4,        2,     -4,      1,      3,        1,       0    ]);
      data.addRow([2,    2,      1,      1,      1,        2,        0,     -3,      2,      0,        0,       0    ]);
      data.addRow([3,   -1,      1,      2,      1,        3,       -4,      0,      3,     -4,       -1,       2    ]);
      data.addRow([4,    4,      1,      4,      4,        4,        4,      3,      4,      4,        4,      -4    ]);
      data.addRow([5,    0,     -2,     -4,     -4,       -4,        2,     -3,     -4,     -3,        0,       4    ]);
      data.addRow([6,    2,      3,      1,     -2,        1,        1,      3,      2,     -2,        1,       0    ]);
      data.addRow([7,   -2,      3,     -1,     -3,       -3,       -2,      3,     -1,     -2,       -1,       2    ]);
      data.addRow([8,   -3,      3,      0,     -2,       -3,       -3,      3,      2,      2,       -2,       2    ]);
      data.addRow([9,   -3,      3,      0,     -3,        0,       -3,      2,      3,      3,       -3,       2    ]);
      data.addRow([10,  -4,      4,      1,     -4,        2,       -4,      4,      4,     -4,       -4,       3    ]);
      data.addRow([11,   4,      3,      0,      3,        0,        1,     -2,      0,     -2,        3,       0    ]);

      alert(data.getNumberOfColumns());
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      // create columns array
      var columns = [];
      // display these data series by default
      var defaultSeries = [1];
      var series = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
          if (i == 0 || defaultSeries.indexOf(i) > -1) {
              // if the column is the domain column or in the default list, display the series
              columns.push(i);
          }
          else {
              // otherwise, hide it
              columns[i] = {
                  label: data.getColumnLabel(i),
                  type: data.getColumnType(i),
                  calc: function () {
                      return null;
                  }
              };
          }
          if (i > 0) {
              // set the default series option
              series[i - 1] = {};
              if (defaultSeries.indexOf(i) == -1) {
                  // backup the default color (if set)
                  if (typeof(series[i - 1].color) !== 'undefined') {
                      series[i - 1].backupColor = series[i - 1].color;
                  }
                  series[i - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
              }
          }
      }

      var options = {
          pointSize: 5,
          width: 1000,
          height: 400,
          series: series,
          curveType: 'function',
          vAxis: { 
            viewWindow:{
              max:5,
              min:-5
            },
            gridlines: { count: 11, color: '#CCC' } 
          },
          chartArea: {width: '60%'},
          hAxis: {                                                               
            title: "Nanas",                                     
            gridlines: { count: 11, color: '#CCC' } 
             ,slantedTextAngle:90 ,textStyle: {fontSize: 13}
          }
      }           

      function showHideSeries () {
          var sel = chart.getSelection();
          // if selection length is 0, we deselected an element
          if (sel.length > 0) {
              // if row is undefined, we clicked on the legend
              if (sel[0].row == null) {
                  var col = sel[0].column;
                  if (columns[col] == col) {
                      // hide the data series
                      columns[col] = {
                          label: data.getColumnLabel(col),
                          type: data.getColumnType(col),
                          calc: function () {
                              return null;
                          }
                      };

                      // grey out the legend entry
                      series[col - 1].color = '#CCCCCC';
                  }
                  else {
                      // show the data series
                      columns[col] = col;
                      series[col - 1].color = null;
                  }
                  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                  view.setColumns(columns);
                  chart.draw(view, options);
              }
          }
      }

      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', showHideSeries);

      // create a view with the default columns
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns(columns);    
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }


  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);    


  </script>                                                                                
  </head>                                                                                    
  <body>                                                                                     
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
      <div id="creativeCommons" style="text-align: center; width: 400px;">
        <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">Code to turn on or off data series by clicking on legend entries</span> by <span xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" property="cc:attributionName">Andrew Gallant</span> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License</a>.
      </div>            
  </body>                                                                                    
  </html>
```

Code Sample 2: ToolTip

```
  function drawChart() {
       var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ["X",
          "Attention Phase Harmony",                        {label: 'Tooltip', role: 'tooltip'}, 
          "Clarity of Periphery",                           {label: 'Tooltip', role: 'tooltip'}, 
          "Body Temperature",                               {label: 'Tooltip', role: 'tooltip'}, 
          "Clarity of Center of Attention",                 {label: 'Tooltip', role: 'tooltip'}],

          [1,    0,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [2,    1,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [3,    1,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [4,    1,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [5,   -2,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [6,    3,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [7,    3,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [8,    3,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [9,    3,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [10,   4,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],
          [11,   3,  "APH",  null,null,null,null,null,null],

          [1,   null,null,   4,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [2,   null,null,   2,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [3,   null,null,  -1,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [4,   null,null,   4,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [5,   null,null,   0,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [6,   null,null,   2,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [7,   null,null,  -2,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [8,   null,null,  -3,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [9,   null,null,  -3,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [10,  null,null,  -4,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],
          [11,  null,null,   4,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null,null,null],

          [1,   null,null,null,null,    0,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [2,   null,null,null,null,    1,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [3,   null,null,null,null,    2,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [4,   null,null,null,null,    4,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [5,   null,null,null,null,   -4,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [6,   null,null,null,null,    1,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [7,   null,null,null,null,   -1,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [8,   null,null,null,null,    0,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [9,   null,null,null,null,    0,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [10,  null,null,null,null,    1,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],
          [11,  null,null,null,null,    0,"tooltip info about product 1",    null,null],

          [1,   null,null,null,null,null,null,  1,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [2,   null,null,null,null,null,null,  1,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [3,   null,null,null,null,null,null,  1,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [4,   null,null,null,null,null,null,  4,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [5,   null,null,null,null,null,null, -4,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [6,   null,null,null,null,null,null, -2,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [7,   null,null,null,null,null,null, -3,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [8,   null,null,null,null,null,null, -2,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [9,   null,null,null,null,null,null, -3,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [10,  null,null,null,null,null,null, -4,"tooltip info about product 1"    ],
          [11,  null,null,null,null,null,null,  3,"tooltip info about product 1"    ]
      ]);




      var options = {
          pointSize: 5,
          width: 1000,
          height: 400,
          curveType: 'function',
          vAxis: { 
            viewWindow:{
              max:5,
              min:-5
            },
            gridlines: { count: 11, color: '#CCC' } 
          },
          chartArea: {width: '60%'},
          hAxis: {                                                               
            title: "Nanas",                                     
            gridlines: { count: 11, color: '#CCC' } 
             ,slantedTextAngle:90 ,textStyle: {fontSize: 13}
          }
      }

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div')); 
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data); 

      chart.draw(view, options);

  }

  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);    


  </script>                                                                                
  </head>                                                                                    
  <body>                                                                                     
      <div id="chart_div"></div>
      <div id="creativeCommons" style="text-align: center; width: 400px;">
        <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US"><img alt="Creative Commons License" style="border-width:0" src="http://i.creativecommons.org/l/by-nc-sa/3.0/88x31.png" /></a><br /><span xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" href="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/InteractiveResource" property="dct:title" rel="dct:type">Code to turn on or off data series by clicking on legend entries</span> by <span xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" property="cc:attributionName">Andrew Gallant</span> is licensed under a <a rel="license" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/deed.en_US">Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License</a>.
      </div>            
  </body>                                                                                    
  </html>
```

Comment: I updated my code example with the capability to handle arbitrary role columns.  [Example jsfiddle using your data](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/6gz2Q/62/).

Comment: Asgallant, You are awesome! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this post a little while ago, and used the base code from asgallant (thanks by the way). Nevertheless, I found another solution which can be easier to implement as I created a utility class for handling the whole process (and I'm using a little trick to avoid changing the Graph data, all is a matter of display style. Instead of changning calc() function to handle line drawing, I just apply a 0 lineWidth style on the serie.

```
column.lineWidth = 0;
```

Code can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/w9b1eyxy/58/

Hope this can help in a near future.